# FFs Github: Permission denied (publickey) fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git, github, public-key-encryption

I'm using VM virtual machine as my Rails working environment. And now I'm trying to upload my project to GitHub. When I run command `git push -u origin master` or `git push origin master` there is an error message like:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

However, I Googled this error and followed the ssh guide I found, it looks like I have pasted the ssh key correctly by running the checking command :`ssh-add -l` and it gives me:
 `2048 d4:05:6d:03:cb:f3:b1:9c:63:7f:74:ce:09:26:be:a2 /home/bruce/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)`

What happened? I don't quite understand. Did I miss something or make a mistake? Somebody help please. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you add the output from `git remote show origin` ?

Comment: Thanks Andomar,  it gives same error message 'Permission denied (publickey). fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly'

Comment: That's very strange, no idea why `git remote show` would try to connect to the server

Comment: Oh i run `ssh -vT git@github.com`  it gives me a lot bunch of debug messages but finally end up with a 'debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).'    looks like i cant get access to git or heroku......Sad

Comment: I doubt github gives everyone shell access ;)  `git push` should be run locally.

Comment: Have you added your public key to GitHub? The last line of an SSH connection attempt isn't all that useful -- everything important was printed before then, and chances are it shows the same message about your public key not being added to your GitHub account.

Comment: @cjc343 yes  i have added to github  in my account setting i saw it